# change href to a semi hardcoded variable with algoliasearch

Tags: javascript, algolia

So basically I'm using AlgoliaSearch and want to be able to let the user clicks on the search results that come up. Since the objectID matches the ID in my database, I was thinking that I can just do something where the a href= can be semi-hardcoded and append or add the id at the end of the html tag.  I've tried getting Javascript's getdocumentbyID, but that doesn't work.

Would appreciate any help on this, thanks.

```
<script>
    var index = client.initIndex('MultipleChoiceQuestion');
    //initialize autocomplete on search input (ID selector must match)
    autocomplete('#aa-search-input', { hint: false }, {
      source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, { hitsPerPage: 25 }),
      //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
      displayKey: 'name',
      //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
      templates: {
        //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          var idx = suggestion.objectID;
          var array = suggestion.tag_list.join('\n');
          return '<div class="aa-highlight column is-2">' +
            array + '</div><div class="aa-mcq column is-4"><a href="" id="search-mcq-id">' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.question.value + '</a></div><div class="column is-4">' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.answer_explanation.value + idx + '</div>';
                          document.getElementById('search-mcq-id').href = idx;

        }
      }
    });

    </script>
```

tl;dr - I want to have the  link to a semi hardcoded link, which would be something like `<A href="example.com/something/OBJECTID">`, but the method that i tried doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to hardcode it, can you just set it in the JS template you're writing? It seems like you're overcomplicating things by trying to set the href after returning JS (note: you can't do anything after you've `return`ed

Maybe try this:

```
var idx = suggestion.objectID;
var array = suggestion.tag_list.join('\n');
return '<div class="aa-highlight column is-2">' +
  array + '</div><div class="aa-mcq column is-4"><a href="/' + idx + '">' +
  suggestion._highlightResult.question.value + '</a></div><div class="column is-4">' +
  suggestion._highlightResult.answer_explanation.value + idx + '</div>';
```